# Why focus is cleared after a click on the body

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, focus, blur

I am using bootstrap, less and jQuery in my app. I wanted to ask you about the focus of elements.

So I have a list of items created with `ul` `li` anchors. I have done a code that makes the anchors to be colored on click and to clear the color on blur.
The problem is when the user clicked wherever on the body, the focus of anchors is cleared by himself.

Do you know what could be the problem behind it?

Comment: But as i understand it, that's expected behaviour. Could you provide minimalistic sample to replicate your issue?

Comment: You keep using that word, "focused" - I don't think it means what you think it means...

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behaviour. But if for some reason you want to keep focused element when clicking anywhere on `body` on non focusable element, you could use following snippet:

```js
//include IIFE if not already including jQuery UI
(function () {
    function focusable(element, isTabIndexNotNaN) {
        var map, mapName, img,
        nodeName = element.nodeName.toLowerCase();
        if ("area" === nodeName) {
            map = element.parentNode;
            mapName = map.name;
            if (!element.href || !mapName || map.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "map") {
                return false;
            }
            img = $("img[usemap='#" + mapName + "']")[0];
            return !!img && $(img).is(':visible');
        }
        return (/^(input|select|textarea|button|object)$/.test(nodeName) ? !element.disabled :
            "a" === nodeName ? element.href || isTabIndexNotNaN : isTabIndexNotNaN) &&
        // the element and all of its ancestors must be visible
        $(element).is(':visible');
    }
    $.extend($.expr[":"], {
        focusable: function (element) {
            return focusable(element, !isNaN($.attr(element, "tabindex")));
        }
    });
})();

$(':focusable').on('blur', function (e) {
    //using a timeout to put logic in event queue
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!$(document.activeElement).is(':focusable')) this.focus();
    }.bind(this), 0);
});
```

```css
/* for demo purpose only*/
a:focus {
    color: red;
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">anchor with href (focusable)</a>
<br/>
<a>anchor without href (unfocusable)</a>
<br/>
<input placeholder="input (focusable)" />
<div>div without tabindex (unfocusable)</div>
<div tabindex="0">div with tabindex (focusable)</div>
<div tabindex="-1">div with tabindex negative (focusable but untabbable)</div>
```